# Spring MimeMessageHelper: AddressException when adding multiple CC

Tags: java, spring, email, mime-message

I need to add multiple CC addresses to my mail message, but I keep getting the following exception:

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal Address (email@email.com;email@email.com,15)
```

Here is my code:

```
final String ccAddress = (String) inputMessageHeaders.get(MailHeaders.CC);
final String[] arrayOfCCAddress = ccAddress.split(";");
for(String cc : arrayOfCCAddress) {
    InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress(cc);
    mimeMessageHelper.setCc(address);
}
```

The original value of ccAddress is "email@email.com;email@email.com"  The actual addresses are valid.  Why is it throwing an exception and adding the ",15" to the end of the CC address?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up waiting to add the cc until right before setting it in the mimehelper, whereas before I was setting it in a message header, which was messing things up.  Never figured out why.